# Image is not passing in carousel in yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I'm using pretty url. The slider is working fine I can see but the imgage is not sliding. I'm not sure if it's due to the prettyurl or I've missed something
The source of my images are - C:\xampp\htdocs\amitopticals\frontend\images.
Code of the index file -

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Amit Opticals';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-index">
    <div class="body-content">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image1.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image2.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image3.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image4.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current output
[image]

**Update**
I've changed the code of this page as following. Please notice that the images of other project's location are working fine. In the below code -

```
<div class="item active">
      <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image1.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>
```

NOT working

```
<div class="item">
      <img src="/pse/advanced/frontend/images/images/image2.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>
```

Working

I'm not sure if I'm missing something.
The complete code of index.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Amit Opticals';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-index">

  <div class="body-content">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="/amitopticals/frontend/images/image1.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="/pse/advanced/frontend/images/images/image2.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="/pse/advanced/frontend/images/images/image3.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="/pse/advanced/frontend/images/images/image4.jpg" alt="PS">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with backend first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^backend/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/image/(.*)$ backend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/backend/web/(assets|css|image)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(backend)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(assets|css|js|img|font)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)$ frontend/web/image/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|image|font)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

add base url In front of image path  `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl`

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'Amit Opticals';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-index">
    <div class="body-content">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/frontend/images/image1.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/frontend/images/image2.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/frontend/images/image3.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/frontend/images/image4.jpg" alt="AO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: same as you've given. I've copied and pasted.

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/images/image2.jpg" alt="AO"> just check remove frontend in url and its not working move image folder to frontend web  <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/web/images/image2.jpg" alt="AO">

Comment: This is also not working  please show your .htacess file

Comment: I've added in the question

Comment: just move your images to frontend/web/image <img src="<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>/web/image/image2.jpg" alt="AO"> and change path like this

Comment: Still the same result. Everything else is working fine. I didn't play much with css or js though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122332/discussion-between-jithin-and-tanmay).